# Put an option value in a input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to put the option value of my select in a input text
i have this:

```
 <select name="typers" id="contact-location" class="form-control">
     <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
     <option value="Twitter">Twitter</option>
     <option value="Google +">Google +</option>
     <option value="Autres">Autre</option>
</select>
```

And when i submit, i want that my input text to get the value of the option selected :

```
 <input type="text" name="typers" value="MySelectedOption"/>
```

I have tried but without success... 
Somebody know how to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('input[name=typers]').val($('#contact-location').val());
```

**[Working Demo on select change](http://jsfiddle.net/Egdx5/)**

Comment: Change `<option value"Facebook">Facebook</option>` to `<option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>` and you're set. It works right now, but just to get valid HTML. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use it:
I assume your submit button id is submit

```
$('#submit').click(function(){

  var text = $('#contact-location').val();

  $('input [name=typers]').val(text);

 })
```

Also i want to tell you your html is wrong input does not have a closing tag.It should be like this:`<input type="text" name="typers" value="MySelectedOption"/>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="Submit"]').click(function(){
    $('input[type="text"').val($('#contact-location').val()); //input selector
});
```

Use this **[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yuq7C/2/)**.

Comment: he want it on submit button click. so there is no need to use this and change event.